# Facebook social login for Android apps NOT on Google Play Store

Tags: android, facebook, apk, facebook-login

We received the message below from FB regarding our Android app. Our app was originally on the PlayStore but is currently not approved / published. We are still using the Play Store link in the field > 'Android: Google Package Name'. Seems Google may have made a change & this link is no longer valid.

While we work on restoring PlayStore approval, the Android app is available as a **direct download**. We don't know how long this process will take. My question is, does FB support Android APKs that are not listed on the PlayStore? Is there a way to use a different link in the field > 'Android: Google Package Name'? Our Android users have used FB login to create accounts so we really need to keep this feature active. If anyone has any input here that would be great. cheers

Message from FB:

> In order to keep our Facebook platform and community safe, we periodically review apps for compliance. We need the following action from you on your app, (), in order to approve your app’s continued operation on our platform.
>
> URL(s) listed on your app dashboard settings could not be accessed for platform compliance review. Kindly make sure that the following field(s) on your app dashboard are working correctly:
> Android: Google Package Name
>
> The corresponding URL(s) should return a successful HTTP status code. You can verify this using the Sharing Debugger.
> Sharing Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/
> Compliant response codes: 200-299
> Violating response codes: 100-199, 300-399, 400-499, 500-599
>
> Please also allowlist the user agent strings or the IP addresses (more secure) used by the crawler. For detailed instructions, please visit: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler.
>
> For Google Package Name(s) and iPhone Store ID(s), please make sure that these are publicly available.
>
> Kindly apply the requested changes to prevent your app from being restricted on our platform. You can check your app dashboard to verify if the violating fields are now compliant, otherwise you will receive an automated alert as soon as we've detected that the fields are compliant.
>
> Thank you for your cooperation in our continued efforts to keep our platform safe.

Comment: Can anybody help here? thx